# Convert System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

.NET compiler will not implicitly convert `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

An explicit cast:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var items = new List<MyType>;

var selectedItems =
  from item in items
  where item.Active 
  select item;

return (List<MyType>)selectedItems;
```

gives this warning:

> Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which inherits from
> both System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable and
> System.Collections.Generic.List

What is best practice here?

Comment: Are you *sure* you need a List? Will IEnumerable, IOrderedEnumerable, ICollection, or IList not do? Generally you should use the least-specific type you can.

Comment: that code doesn't return an  `IOrderedEnumerable<MyType>`, show your **actual** code

Comment: Was this a CS0266-error? If so, maybe you could consider it adding it in the title or the body (your edit-queue was full)? Anyway, your question helped. Take care & good luck.

Answer (score 28):

Simply use the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension:

```
return selectedItems.ToList();
```

You should be aware though: *best practice* (since you asked) would actually want you to return an `IEnumerable<MyType>` in most cases. Therefore, you may want to change your signature in this way:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> MyFunction()
{
    // your code here
}
```

And THEN, if you need to, have the function's result in a list:

```
var myList = MyFunction().ToList();
```

Unless you have a very precise reason of returning a `List<>` type, I strongly suggest that you don't.

Hope that helps.

Comment: He didn't show the method's signature, which may very well return an `IEnumerable<T>`. In which case, calling `ToList` is the standard for avoiding delayed evaluation/multiple evaluations.

Comment: The specific reasons between returning a composable `IEnumerable<T>` and a concrete `ICollection<T>` come down to whether or not a specific snapshot of those items are needed at invocation time, or if the collection will be iterated many times and does not need to reflect changes in the enumerated source.

Comment: @dcastro I am well aware of that but since the question specifically asked for advice about best practices *AND* wasn't showing the method's signature, I thought it was worth mentionning.

Comment: @codekaizen The `IEnumerable<>` type can also be used as a way to abstract the nature of the returned sequence. It's up to the method to determine whether or not it should return a snapshot; in both cases though, returning `IEnumerable<>` should be the preferred practice IMHO. Unless, as I said, the method is meant to return a modifiable sequence.

Comment: Yea, that is the point - you don't know anything about the sequence when it is returned as `IEnumerable<T>` - so if you know you need a snapshot with no uncertainty about it, then use `ICollection<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: @codekaizen that goes backwards from what a properly abstracted function should be. It's up to the *caller* to decide whether or not he cares about the enumerable possibly not being a snapshot. If it *does* want to guarantee working with a snapshot then *he* gets to convert it. No way this is the function's responsibility.

Comment: @codekaizen allow me to add a precision: the function *may* want to ensure that the returned result won't be executed again and again, but it *still* should return an `IEnumerable<>` type regardless. The return type should *not* serve any guarantees purposes other than the return value being a sequence. Just look at the Framework and popular libraries, you'll see for yourself that it's the preferred way.

Comment: That is true for a library, but that's not the point I'm arguing. This is his function and this is a decision he has to make. There are valid arguments for either pattern, and like any pattern, trade-offs which must be managed. For a library, the abstraction of `IEnumerable<T>` is almost always correct, but for internal classes it is not so clear, and other factors bear more weight in the consideration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49677/discussion-between-crono-and-codekaizen)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension:

```
selectedItems.ToList();
```